# Estoy tratando de leer un archivo XML y el resultado asignarlo a los input correspondintes pero no los asigna

Tags: php, javascript, xml

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Importador</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" te cype="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>


    <form name="f1" id="f1">
    <table width="506" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Cliente:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cliente" id="cliente" ></td>
          <td>Nombre contacto</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="contacto" id="contacto" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>direccion de despacho:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" ></td>
          <td>comuna</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="comuna" id="comuna" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ciudad:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="ciudad"></td>
          <td>comision</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="comision"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>condicion de pago:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="condicionpago"></td>
          <td>orden de compra</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="ordencompra"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>fecha de entrega</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fechaentrega"></td>
          <td>vendedor</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="vendedor"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>fecha VB:</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="fechavb"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table> 
    </form>

    <?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file('data.xml');
    $count=0;

    foreach($xml as $data)
    {
    $clien = $data->cliente;
    $contac = $data->contacto;
    $dir = $data->direccion;
    $comu = $data->comuna;
    $ciudad = $data->ciudad;
    $comis = $data->comision;
    $condicp = $data->condicionpago;
    $ordenc = $data->ordencompra;
    $fentre = $data->fechaentrega;
    $vende = $data->vendedor;
    $fvb = $data->fechavb;
    }
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.f1.cliente.value = "<?php echo $clien; ?>"
    document.f1.contacto.value = "<?php echo $contac; ?>"
    document.f1.direccion.value = "<?php echo $dir; ?>"
    document.f1.comuna.value = "<?php echo $comu; ?>"
    document.f1.ciudad.value = "<?php echo $ciudad; ?>"
    document.f1.comision.value = "<?php echo $comis; ?>"

</script>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: En la pregunta aparece cortado, pero esto sería un solo archivo php y todo el código está en el mismo orden en que se presenta en la pregunta?

Comment: Ya lo edite. esta así tal cual. si coloco valores numéricos o texto los toma, pero con las variables de php no.

Comment: Me parece que te están faltando los ';' finales en el javascript que generás dinamicamaente. Y tené en cuenta que si el xml no está bajo tu control, asignar valores así en el js, te expone a xss. Tenés que "escapar" el contenido de las variables para js antes de setearlas. Una forma generalmente aceptada es usar json_encode. Si buscas infomración sobre este tema vas a ver que hay mucho debate sobre como hacerlo. Una buena solución puede ser la que usa Wordpress esc_js() (que es de wordpress aunque podes ver los fuentes), https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_js/

Answer (score 0):

siempre es bueno hacer pequeños ejemplos, en el mismo archivo PHP antes de poner el código HTML puse mi variable var que es igual a un string "hola", después dentro del head pongo una funcion window.onload para que al momento de cargar la página los valores PHP se asignen a los input's con la función de JS, espero te funcione, si pones el codigo PHP en la parte de abajo del HTML saldrá error indicando que la variable $var no esta definida.

```
<?php $var = 'hola'; ?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <script src="funciones/funciones.js"></script>
 <script>
   
   window.onload= function colocarValor(){

    document.getElementById('nombre_prueba').value = "<?php echo $var; ?>";

   }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
  
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" id="Formulario">
  <div id="oculto">
  <label for="nombre_prueba">Nombre:</label>
   <input type="text" name="nombre_prueba" placeholder="Nombre:" id="nombre_prueba">
  </div>
   <label for="colores_prueba">Colores:</label>
   <select name="colores_prueba" id="colores_prueba">
    <option value="">Selecciona</option>
    <option value="rojo">Rojo</option>
    <option value="azul">Azul</option>
   </select><br>

   <label for="ocultar">Ocultar:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ocultar" onclick="ocultarInput()" name="ocultar"><br>
     <input type="submit" name="enviar" onclick="validarElementos()" id="enviar">

 
 </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre, tenia un error de como estaba leyendo el XML, se creaba un bucle y siempre me daba "vacio", sin valor.

ahora entre en otro dilema, como puedo hacer para seleccionar el archivo XML en un input file y lo ubique para que lo lea al momento de seleccionarlo.

$xml=simplexml_load_file('data.xml'); <- osea la ruta o el archivo se asignaría de una vez.